# Is there an easy way to uv map a circle to a half of a sphere?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

The default map of a sphere is a square but i'm trying to map a circle to the top half of the sphere and doing it manually is tedious and inaccurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have half a sphere:

[image]

go to orthongraphic top view (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>, and  <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>  to togle orhto or perspective)

select all faces, press <kbd>U</kbd>, to unwrap, and select ***Project from view (bounds)***

[image]

The **bounds** option means that blender fit the UV map to fit the bounds of the UV image. Note that this will only work without distortion if the image used for UV mapping is square.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for!